# Is there an explicit expression for a bijection between [0,1] and (0,1)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to find an explicit expression for a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$. I've seen some between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$, but I can't seem to find one between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I linked it in my answer to your other question.

Comment: Can we have piecewise defined functions?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/160738

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:
$[0,1] = [0,1/2] \cup (1/2,1]$ and $(0,1) = (0,1/2] \cup (1/2, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

What about $\;f:[0,1]\to(0,1)\;$ defined as

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}\cfrac13,&x=0\\{}\\\cfrac1{3^{n+2}},&x=\cfrac1{3^n}\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\\{}\\x,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: This is nice and clean. It seems to me that you could replace $3$ with any other integer $\ge 2$. Is there a reason why you chose $3$ instead of $2$?

Comment: @Théophile Nop, you chose that...

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_0 = \{\frac1{2^{i+1}}, i \in \Bbb N\}$, $X_1 = \{1 - \frac1{2^{i+1}}, i \in \Bbb N\}$

We then define $f$ as follows:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x\ \text{if}\ x \not\in X_0\cup X_1\\
\frac14, x = 0\\
\frac34, x = 1\\
\frac1{2^{i+2}}\ \text{if}\ x\in X_0, x = \frac1{2^{i+1}}\\
1 - \frac{1}{2^{i+2}}, x \in X_1, x = 1 - \frac1{2^{i+1}}
\end{cases}$$

This applies the idea to make a bijection from $[0, 1]$ to $(0, 1]$ two times, one for each end of the interval.